# PHP array combining every other element

Tags: php

I have an object with several properties that creates a multi dimensional array.  I'm trying to figure out how to create a new array that combines two seperate objects into one.  It would go from this:

```
array(
    object_1(
       'id' => '1',
       'name' => 'joe'
       etc....),
    object_2(
       'id' => '2',
       'name' => 'jessica',
       etc....)
    object_3(
       'id' => '3',
       'name' => 'tim',
       etc....)
    object_4(
       'id' => '4',
       'name' => 'tammy',
       etc....)
    );
```

And become:

```
array(
    object_1(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'joe',
        etc...
        'id2' = > '2',
        'name2' => 'jessica',
        etc...)
    object_2(
        'id' => '3',
        'name' => 'tim',
        etc...
        'id2' = > '4',
        'name2' => 'tammy',
        etc...)
```

So, I need to combine the data from alternating elements, and also change the key in all the second objects so it doesn't match the first.  Make sense?  Sorry if it doesn't, I'll try to clarify if you need!

Thanks for any help....

EDIT: first two stdclass objects according to print_r:

```
[results] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [email] => sample@info.com
                [message] => Create another test
                [image] => 138.png
                [fid] => 53
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [email] => info@sample.com
                [message] => none
                [image] => 330.jpg
                [fid] => 52
            )
```

and I want it to become:

```
[results] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [email] => sample@info.com
                [message] => Create another test
                [image] => 138.png
                [fid] => 53
                [email2] => info@sample.com
                [message2] => none
                [image2] => 330.jpg
                [fid2] => 52
            )
```

Does that clarify?

Comment: What's your question? It seems like a simple `for` loop should do it, so what have you tried?

Comment: As the OP sits, the grouping doesn't make sense, and should NOT be implemented. In first example each object demonstrates an atomic set of data as it should be. Unless there is some logical grouping you are not showing us, you are better off not touching it.

Comment: When combining the data what are you combining it by? I can't see in your example why you would combine 1 and 2 together but not put 3 and 4 in that 1 group too.

Comment: @kpsuperplane He said he's combining each adjacent pair: 0+1, 2+3, 4+5, etc.

Comment: @Mike Purcell It just looks like pagination/chunking to me

Comment: @Patashu: What's throwing me off is that he is trying to combine object attributes, not atomic objects within a multi-dim array. Example #2 should be an array of objects where the first element of the array has two more elements with joe and jessica objects, then second element has tim and tammy objects.

Comment: It's not totally clear what your data structure is. You wrote "multi dimensional array", but your diagram shows objects, not a second level of arrays. So what is the second level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's actually a multi-dimensional array, not an array of objects, this should do it:

```
$new_array = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i +=2) {
  $new_array[] = $array[$i];
  foreach ($array[$i+1] as $key => $value) {
    $new_array[$i/2][$key.'2'] = $value;
  }
}
```

EDIT: For an array of objects, it becomes:

```
$new_array = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i +=2) {
  $new_array[] = $array[$i];
  foreach (get_object_vars($array[$i+1] as $key => $value) {
    $new_array[$i/2]->{$key.'2'} = $value;
  }
}
```

This will only work for public properties.

Comment: Barmar, thank you for the help!  Your answer looks great, but I'm afraid I am dealing with objects.  Sorry I was misleading with what I said about multi-dimensional arrays.  I need to combine object 0+1, object 2+3...so forth.

Comment: Are these public properties that you can assign directly, or do you have to go through an object API to set them?

Comment: Yes, perfect, your second option did the trick.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i+=2) {
   $id = $array[$i]['id'];
   $name = $array[$i]['name'];
   $id2 = $array[$i+1]['id'];
   $name2 = $array[$i+1]['name'];
}
```

or

```
$newarray = array();
$j=0;
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i+=2) {
    $newarray[$j]['id'] = $array[$i]['id'];
    $newarray[$j]['nae'] = $array[$i]['name'];
    $newarray[$j]['id2'] = $array[$i+1]['id'];
    $newarray[$j]['name2'] = $array[$i+1]['name'];
    $j++;
}
```